# Image URL javascript regular expression to accommodate for special urls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have an image url regular expression which is being used to validate a image on the form using `ng-pattern` directive.

Currently I'm struggling to accomodate for cases like `https://google.com.png`. Any help would be really appreciated.

Regex:

```
'^((?!mailto:)(?:(?:http|https|ftp)://)(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[0-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:(/|\\?|#)[^\\s]*)?)\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|PNG|JPG|JPEG|GIF)$'
```

Better to view here:

https://regex101.com/r/dH1wT6/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

Comment: You just use the regex to match the URL and then append to this regex whatever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying the regex :

```regex
^(?!mailto)(?:https?|ftp):\/(?:\/?(?:[.#@?=]?[a-z0-9\u00a1-\uffff]+)+)+[.]?(?:png|jpe?g|gif)$
```

Need to use the i flag for this to make the search not case sensitive.

But you should verify with your list of url's if this allows to much or to little.

Can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/jZ8oN2/2)

If you put the regex in a javascript string, don't forget that you need to backslash the backslashes.